# How do I install Intel Graphics drivers under Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, 17.10

I am running on Ubuntu 17.10, and I want to install the Intel Graphics Tool (version 2.0.6). It installs fine, however running it results in the below error message:

[image: error]

> Distribution not supported

What can I do to fix this, if anything?

Comment: You do not need to install additional drivers for Intel graphics.

Comment: @dobey There are some edge cases where drivers are necessary. Usually not, but there is a reason.

Comment: @KazWolfe Unless one knows specifically that there is a bug fixed in a newer version of the driver, or it improves performance for that particular CPU, installing additional Intel drivers is generally poor advice and causes confusion. It also depends on which part of the set of drivers, the fixes were.